# Custom Post Type List View Column Height & Width

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I created a custom post type for creating different type of charts in wordpress. And created a list view column to preview the chart created in each post type. Everything working fine, but the preview chart is showing in original size. I need to get it in small size just to show preview.

Please have a look at SCREENSHOT HERE: http://s14.postimg.org/szyowvzqp/screenshot_33.png

How can I make the chart preview small in size?

### UPDATED DETAILS:

I wrapped the chart with new  to set height and width 100px. here is screenshot: http://s14.postimg.org/gcixkdktt/screenshot_35.png Unfortunately, this cut off the chart instead of getting the charts small as the canvas height & width are set. Here is result: http://s14.postimg.org/8iibyzd0x/screenshot_34.png

Comment: can you please add the jsfiddle of your code.

Comment: Hello @JPrakash I am doing this in Wordpresss Admin panel. I don't know how to use jsfiddle. Just added a little more to my question. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to add custom styles to wp admin. Either by putting them in the `<head>`or by properly enqueuing them with (this is the preferred way I guess):

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_styles' );

function load_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin_css_foo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style-foo.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin_css_bar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style-bar.css' );
}
```

You could then specify a `max-height` for the column holding the chart, e.g.:

```
.chart {
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I already did something like this and wrapped the chart with new <div class="chart_preview"> to set height and with 100px. here is screenshot: http://s14.postimg.org/gcixkdktt/screenshot_35.png Unfortunately, this cut off the chart instead of getting the charts small as the canvas height & width are set. Here is result: http://s14.postimg.org/8iibyzd0x/screenshot_34.png

Comment: remove the inline styles from the chart. that is what's preventing the `canvas` element to scale correctly.